# PHP refresh page if certain slug or ID

Tags: php, time, slug, page-refresh

I'm trying to get a page refresh once after a set amount of seconds only on a set page.

So something like

```
if is_page('test.php') {
refresh page 5000(once);
} else
continue
```

Comment: There's no officially supported way to do this in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by jQuery
like

```
 window.setTimeout(function() {location.href="URL of test.php"}, 5000);
```

Comment: Note that this is not jquery but pure vanilla JS

Comment: this way it will refresh after 5 seconds even after the refresh. The OP clearly stated: "I'm trying to get a page refresh once"

Comment: Okay, Then you set a session variable after refresh the page once, check that same variable, Like if variable not exist run the code otherwise not.

Comment: It would be nice to edit your answer and add that. I added the answer with a URL param. A session var is a nice option too

Comment: But in this case {location.href="URL of test.php"} is more like a redirect right? It "sends" the page there. I want the code to detect if it's a certain page and only in that case do a refresh once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you can:

```
if(is_page('test.php') && !isset($_GET['r'])){
    header("Refresh: 5;url='http://zasite.com/test.php?r=1'");
}
```

NOTE: This can only be done if the headers have not already been sent http://php.net/manual/ro/function.headers-sent.php otherwise you will end up with a warning and the refresh will not work. A workaround would be:

```
if(is_page('test.php') && !isset($_GET['r'])){
    if(!headers_sent()){
        header("Refresh: 5;url='http://zasite.com/test.php?r=1'");
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" ; url=http://zasite.com/test.php?r=1>';
    }
}
```

OR - PHP with Gyandeep Sharma's JS answer

```
if(is_page('test.php') && !isset($_GET['r'])){
    if(!headers_sent()){
        header("Refresh: 5;url='http://zasite.com/test.php?r=1'");
    } else {
        echo '<script>window.setTimeout(function () {location.href="http://zasite.com/test.php?r=1";}, 5000);</script>';
    }
}
```